# Scrape table from ASX page

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to scrape the table found on this static page:

http://www.asx.com.au/prices/targetratetracker.htm

Using a simple UI based scraper found [here](https://boilerpipe-web.appspot.com/) to test, you can see that it does not return the table even when using the `KeepEverythingExtractor` setting.

Using Inspector on the `targetratetracker.htm` page we can see the following:

```
A Parser-blocking, cross-origin script, http://www.adobetag.com/d4/v2/.../amc.js, is invoked via document.write.
```

I am agnostic as to which library or language to use, just want to know if there's a way around the blocker (if that is indeed the problem).

Comment: so you want achieve that using javascript or python?

Comment: Ideally with JS but a solution using Beautiful Soup is also fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This page uses frame which means the page contains the other page, 
[image]

the URL is :
    http://www.asx.com.au/data/trt/TargetRateTracker.htm

Comment: Yes, I just found this out myself and came back to post it, only to see you beat me to it.